# Increase new invoice number, sometimes duplicated

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this code-snippet:

```
$invoiceNumber = InvoiceNumbers::where('vendor', $request->user()->vendorId)->orderByDesc('invoice_number')->limit(1)->first();
$invoiceNumber ? $newInvoiceNumber = $invoiceNumber->invoice_number++ : $newInvoiceNumber = 1;
$invoiceNumber = InvoiceNumbers::create(['invoice_number' => $newInvoiceNumber, 'vendor' => $request->user()->vendorId]);
```

Unfortunately sometimes, when the scripts runs two times parallel the same invoice number would be created in two entries - Is there an option how I can prevent this? Like with table locks or something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an auto-increment column in your database, or at least a `UNIQUE` constraint on the invoice number column, and regenerate a new id if it fails to insert due to the `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: In my opinion thats a flaw in the design of the database. Why would need to actively set an id, if the database can do that for you with auto increment? The solution would probably to do that. And afterwards adjust the code to 1. start a transaction 2. insert the data you need into the database or create a placeholder 3. get the generated id from the database 4. update the row accordingly if you need to 5. commit changes = make changes final. if anything goes wrong during the transaction just rollback.

Comment: `Is there an option how I can prevent this`...yes, this is exactly what the auto-increment feature in your database was invented for. It guarantees that a unique ID will be created for every row which is inserted. Getting your application code to generate the ID is never a good idea - as you've now discovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between invoicenumber++ and ++invoicenumber;

```
<?php
    $count = 1;
    $var = $count++; #count is assigned to $var, then +1 added.
    #var now equals 1, count = 2
    echo $var; #outputs 1

    $count = 1;
    $var = ++$count; #count is incremented, then assigned
    echo $var; #outputs 2
?>
```

This might solve your problem, but it's advised that if the invoice number is unique and auto increments it would be best to do this on the database level. You can handle this in one of two ways:

- Make InvoiceNumber unique and AutoIncrements, below is sql code, replace it with your relevant column and table name

  ALTER TABLE invoices
  MODIFY InvoiceNumber INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE;
- Make invoice number unique, and wrap the insert in a try-catch{} statement, that increments it again if the SQL throws an error.

  ```
  <?php
      try{
          $invoice = new Invoice;
          $invoice->invoice_number = $invoice_number;
          $invoice->save();
      }catch (Exception $e) {
          $invoice_number++;
          $invoice = new Invoice;
          $invoice->invoice_number = $invoice_number;
          $invoice->save();
      }
  ?>
  ```